# How are negative numbers represented in 32-bit signed integer?

Tags: binary, numbers

How are negative number represented in 32-bit signed integer?
Is it two's or one's complement? or the last bit on the left is like a flag?
For example: (-10)

Comment: In what context? Different systems/platforms will do things differently.

Comment: Do you mean "first bit on the left"?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Most computers these days use [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) for signed integers, but it can vary by hardware architecture, programming language, or other platform-specific issues.

For a two's-complement representation, the most-significant ("leftmost") bit is referred to as the *sign bit*, and it will be set for a negative integer and clear for a non-negative integer.  However, it is more than just a "flag".  See the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) for more information.

Comment: So the front bit will 1 for negative and 0 for positive? What about 0?

Comment: Zero is represented by all bits being zero.

Answer (score 6):

I think the answer is `0110`, preceeded by 1 repeated 28 times, therefore it looks like:

`1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0110;`

Steps:

1. bit representation for 10 is:

   `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1010;`
2. `0->1` and `1->0` for all the bits:

   `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0101;`
3. add 1 to the last bit, and propagate to the bit ahead, done!

   `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0110;`

===

You can verify by adding it with 10, and you will get 0 for all bits. As mentioned above, it is 2-based and follows two's complement.

Comment: clearly explained. Please can you use this method of explanation to explain how floating point numbers are stored.

Answer (score 4):

Usually it's twos-complement.

Answer (score 4):

From the C99 standard:

> For signed integer types, the bits of
>   the object representation shall be
>   divided into three groups: value bits,
>   padding bits, and the sign bit. There
>   need not be any padding bits; there
>   shall be exactly one sign bit. Each
>   bit that is a value bit shall have the
>   same value as the same bit in the
>   object representation of the
>   corresponding unsigned type (if there
>   are M value bits in the signed type
>   and N in the unsigned type, then M =
>   N). If the sign bit is zero, it shall
>   not affect the resulting value. If the
>   sign bit is one, the value shall be
>   modified in one of the following ways:
>
> — the corresponding value with sign
>   bit 0 is negated (sign and magnitude);
>
> — the sign bit has the value -(2N)
>   (two’s complement);
>
> — the sign bit has the value -(2N - 1)
>   (ones’ complement).
>
> Which of these applies is
>   implementation-defined, as is whether
>   the value with sign bit 1 and all
>   value bits zero (for the first two),
>   or with sign bit and all value bits 1
>   (for ones’ complement), is a trap
>   representation or a normal value. In
>   the case of sign and magnitude and
>   ones’ complement, if this
>   representation is a normal value it is
>   called a negative zero.

Answer (score 1):

```
0xFFFFFFFF = -1
0xFFFFFFFE = -2
0xFFFFFFFD = -3
...
```

& so on

Answer (score 0):

The most significant bit (last bit on the left) is set for negative numbers.

Comment: Do you mean "first bit on the left"?

Comment: How about "first bit FROM the left" or "Last bit FROM the right". :)

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference: `negation` -> `adding one`.

Take `5` as an example in 8 bits, quoted from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement#From_the_ones.27_complement)

```
to convert 5 to -5: 0000 0101 - flip -> 1111 1010 - add one -> 1111 1011
```

There is a trick to convert a number from positive to negative or vice verse:

Adding them ignoring their signed bit (the leftmost bit) will give you `2^N` (where N is the amount of the bits to represent the number).

As the example above in *8-bit* representation the sum of `5 (0000 0101)` and `-5 (1111 1011)` will give you `1 0000 0000` which is (2 ^ 8).