# What is the correct way to represent a negative number in binary system?

Tags: binary

I've seen two ways to represent a negative number in binary system. One approach is having the left-most digit as a signed bit, 0 indicating positive and 1 indicating negative. Another approach is taking 2'complement of a positive number to get its opposite number.

Comment: What do you mean by "correct"? Most systems use 2s-complement these days but I wouldn't call it "correct".

Comment: Voting to close as primarily opinion-based (which in fact this is). Either system works well, neither is 'better' than the other.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931630/how-are-negative-numbers-represented-in-32-bit-signed-integer

Comment: Yes `2'complement`

Answer (score 0):

Usually you want to use the second approach. It allows you to keep your addition methods unchanged.

Google will answere this question for you ;-)