# Finding the difference between a negative and positive binary Number

Tags: c, binary

I know that we can represent binary Numbers in several ways, but I am really not sure how to distinguish a positive binary number from a negative one.

If we have the number `+13`, then its binary representation looks like this:
`1101`

and its negative representation looks like this:

`11101`

What I understand is that if you need to distinguish them, then the presence of `0` is important in number `+13`:

`01101`

Even so, I still cannot distinguish between:

`11101 ///Here is the representation of -13`

and:

`11101 ///Here is the representation of +29`

I understand that here is used another scheme  called "two's complement" which I need to apply it.

How can I distinguish those two binary representations?

Comment: you cannot, unless you know what the exact type used in the program. note that `11011` is probably not negative, since the `1` is the most significant bit of the size of the type used. There's ambiguity for -1 and 255 for instance because it can be written `11111111`

Comment: it depends on how it is used, so for instance what machine instructions are used to process it. Is `11011` an unsigned number, a twos complement number or a sign/magnitude number? Just going by the fact that its binary representation is `11011`, you can't know. Heck, it might not even represent a number, but something entirely different.

Comment: Have a look at this related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931630/how-are-negative-numbers-represented-in-32-bit-signed-integer

Comment: `11011` would mean "signed magnitude", which is one way (uncommon) to represent a negative sign. Other ways are two's complement (most common) and one's complement (uncommon). To make things worse, C allows all three forms. But real-world computers almost exclusively use two's complement.

Comment: `1011` binary is 11 decimal, not 13.

Comment: @Lundin So this means that if on my System the size of `int` is `4` and there is the number `13`, then its negative representation would be `10000000 00000000 00000000 00001101` because left bit it is set to `1`. Am I right ?

Comment: @Chux You right. Corected :d

Comment: @MichaelB. If you have somehow found an exotic computer which uses signed magnitude, then yes. An x86 PC would use 2's complement: `11111111 11111111 11111111 11110011`. Which happens to be the bitwise inverse + 1.

Comment: @chux I tought that  the signed `11111111.11111111.11111111.11111111` means `-1` in 2's Complement and `10000000 00000000 00000000 00001101` means `-13`.

Comment: @MichaelB. `10000000 00000000 00000000 00001101` as a binary number is  2,147,483,661.  As a 32-bit 2's complement binary number, it is -2,147,483,635

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same sequence of bits can have radically different meanings based on context.

Integer types have a fixed number of bits - the C language definition mandates that the signed `int` type must be able to represent *at least* the range `[-32,767...32,767]`, meaning an `int` must be *at least* 16 bits wide<sup>1</sup>.

There are several different ways to represent signed integers.  The most common is 2's complement, but some architectures may use 1's complement or sign-magnitude.

To flip the sign on a 2's complement number, do a bitwise negation and add 1 (this example assumes 8 bit integers):

```
00001101 == 13
11110010 + 1 == 11110011 == -13

11110011 == -13
00001100 + 1 == 00001101 == 13
```

One of the chief advantages of 2's complement is that you have a single representation for 0, and it gives you a slightly wider range of values - `[-2n-1..2n-1-1]`

To flip the sign on a 1's complement number, you simply do a bitwise negation:

```
00001101 == 13
11110010 == -13

11110010 == -13
00001101 == 13
```

With 1's complement, you have positive and negative representations for 0 - `00000000` and `11111111` - and the range is `[-2n-1-1..2n-1-1]`

With sign-magnitude, you leave the value bits as-is and flip the sign bit:

```
00001101 == 13
10001101 == -13
```

Like 1's complement, you get two encodings for positive and negative 0 - `00000000` and `10000000`.

Unsigned integer types have the same width as their signed counterparts, and their range is `[0..2n-1]`.

So, the bit sequence `11110011` can mean -13 in 2's complement, -12 in 1's complement, -115 in sign-magnitude, or 243 unsigned.

---

1. Note that some architectures may use padding bits, such that it takes more than 16 bits to represent 32,767.

Comment: Nice answer. MIsc: Its `1s` _ones’ complement_ not `1's`, but `2's` is OK for _two’s complement_.  The `n values bits` of `unsigned` could be one less than `n` of `int` due to padding, yet I doubt a system will every try that again.

Answer (score 3):

As the other guys say the question *can I distinguish those two binary representations* as no sense. A sequence of bits is neutral, when you transform it in a number you do the transformation for a given representation. It can represent an *int*, an *unsigned int*, a *float* or anything you want. It is like if I ask you what is a *coin*, this word exists (at least ?) in English and in French with a totally different meaning (the french word *coin* means *corner* in English), to answer me you need to choose a language, you cannot answer without.

About the "two's complement", it is the way compatible for the standard representation used in our CPU to change the sign of *signed int*. The *first complement* is to replace all 0 by 1 and all 1 by 0, the *second complement* is to add 1 to the previous result.

Supposing the word has 5 bits, the *int* value 13 is 01101 in binary. If we want -13 the *first complement* on 13 gives 10010, adding 1 that gives 10011.

But still having 5 bits words, 10011 for an *unsigned int* correspond to the value 19.

For an *int* on 5 bits the lower negative number is by definition 10000, if we try to change its sign : first complement = 01111, adding 1 = 10000 ! In fact there is an overflow, 5 bits are not enough.

Comment: I undestand now.

Comment: *coin* is the cry of a duck in french too. I had to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

The binary value is open to the *encoding*.

**1101**

`1101`<sub>2</sub> has the value of 13<sub>10</sub> when there is no encoded sign bit.

When a sign-bit is used, the *width* `N` is also important.
When  `N > 4`, 
using [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), [1s' complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Ones'_complement), [sign magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Signed_magnitude_representation), the value is still 13<sub>10</sub>.

**11101**

If `11101`<sub>2</sub> was saved in `unsigned` field of size 5 or more, the value is 29<sub>10</sub>.

If `11101`<sub>2</sub> was saved in a 5-bit `signed int` field, the value is depends on the `int` encoding (which is certainly 2's complement).

2's complement: -3<sub>10</sub>
1s' complement: -2<sub>10</sub>
Sign magnitude: -13<sub>10</sub>  (Apparently OP's initial view)

Answer (score -1):

Let's say you have 5 bit computer. 5 bits divided into 1 sign bit + 4 number bits.
Limits are 2^4-1 to -2^4 i.e. 15 to -16.
13=01101
-13= 10010 : 2's complement representation. It won't be 18 because 18 can't fit in the range.